# Form an array list in the another format using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associate array format like $aa. Need to form an array list in the different format.

```
$aa = Array
 (
'Std'=> Array
    (
         'Add/Remove/Modify',
         'Create',
         'Addition',
         'repository',
    ),

'Agl' => Array
    (
         'Disk',
         'center',
         'Service ',
    ),

'Error' => Array
    (
         'VM',
         'DNS',
         'Upgrade',
    ),

'Hyg' => Array
    (
       'Health',
        'VM ',
        'Clear',
    ),

'Int' => Array
    (
         'iExecute',
         'Storage',
         'CMDB',
    ),

'Jor' => Array
    (
         'Uptime ',
         'Server ',
        'Report',
    ),

'Mon' => Array
    (
         'jobs',
         'mon',
         'SLA',
    ),

);
```

Have to form the array like the below format in PHP.
Help me on this. Thanks in advance

```
$res = array( 
    array( 
            'Add/Remove/Modify','Disk', 'VM','Health', 'iExecute','Uptime ', 'jobs'
    ),
    array(
        'Create','center', 'DNS', 'VM ','Storage','Server ', 'mon'
    ),
    array(
        'Addition', 'Service ', 'Upgrade', 'Clear', 'CMDB', 'Report','SLA'
    ),
    array('repository')
    );
```

Comment: The result should be like this. 
      1) $aa array of 0th column is first array of $res
       array( 
        'Add/Remove/Modify','Disk', 'VM','Health', 'iExecute','Uptime ', 'jobs'
         ),
      2) $aa array of 1st column is second array of $res
      array(
        'Create','center', 'DNS', 'VM ','Storage','Server ', 'mon'
      ),
      3) $aa array of 2nd column is third array of $res
      array(
        'Addition', 'Service ', 'Upgrade', 'Clear', 'CMDB', 'Report','SLA'
      ),
      4) $aa array of 3rd column is forth array of $res 
     array('repository')

Comment: Loop over `$aa['Std']`, and access the items in the other sub-arrays via the corresponding index (if they exist.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) takes an arbitrary number of arrays as arguments(it can do more than the "standard case" with one array), and then step through them one element at a time. A "set"(array) of the current element(s) of each array is passed to a callback function that can "mold" each set of values the way you want them to be (which..is just the way they were passed to the callback, in this case :)).

It's just the small issue of some of the arrays being longer than others(in that case the size of the set handed to the callback is still the same, but with null values from the shorter arrays). Hence the call to [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

As you perhaps already know by now, telling the story "backwards", we pass the contents of `$aa` - as separate arrays - to array_map(), with the aid of [the spread operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array)(The "outer" one, the spread operator in the function head compacts all the arguments to the array `$args`). To unpack the array PHP wants it to be numeric, which `$aa` isn't. Hence [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
print_r(
    array_map(
        function(...$args) {
            return array_filter($args);
        },
        ...array_values($aa)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_column` should help you out. If you know the maximum items you can have in one of your arrays, you do not need to find the max, like I'm doing here.

```
$array = [
    'a' => [
        '1.1',
        '1.2',
        '1.3',
        '1.4',
    ],
    'b' => [
        '2.1',
        '2.2',
        '2.3',
        '2.4',
        '2.5',
    ],
    'c' => [
        '3.1',
        '3.2',
        '3.3',
    ],
];

$max_items = 0;
foreach ($array as $sub) {
    $count = count($sub);
    if ($count > $max_items) {
        $max_items = $count;
    }
}

$new_array = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $max_items; $i++) {
    $new_array[] = array_column(array_values($array), $i);
} 

var_dump($new_array);
```

Result

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "1.1"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "2.1"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "3.1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "1.2"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "2.2"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "3.2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "1.3"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "2.3"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "3.3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "1.4"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "2.4"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "2.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the largest number of columns in one of the inner arrays by using max and array_map. Then you can get each individual column through [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) which takes integer keys as well for the index.

```
$result = [];
$maxNumberOfColumns = max(array_map('count', $aa));

for ($i = 0; $i < $maxNumberOfColumns; $i++) {
    $result[] = array_column($aa, $i);
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($result, true), '</pre>';
```

The result:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Add/Remove/Modify
            [1] => Disk
            [2] => VM
            [3] => Health
            [4] => iExecute
            [5] => Uptime 
            [6] => jobs
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Create
            [1] => center
            [2] => DNS
            [3] => VM 
            [4] => Storage
            [5] => Server 
            [6] => mon
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Addition
            [1] => Service 
            [2] => Upgrade
            [3] => Clear
            [4] => CMDB
            [5] => Report
            [6] => SLA
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => repository
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses two loops, the first helps us determine the maximum length of the $res array while the second loops through each value to populate the $res sub-arrays.

```
$res = [];
$len_arr = [];

// Figure out the length of the $res array
foreach ($aa as $key => $value) {
    array_push($len_arr, count($value));
}

//Populate the $res array with $len number of empty arrays
$len = max($len_arr);
$res = array_fill(0, $len, []);

//Loop through each array to populate the inner array of the $res array
foreach ($aa as $key => $value) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++) {
        array_push($res[$i], $value[$i]);
    }
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($res, true), '</pre>';
```

The result of printing $res is shown below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Add/Remove/Modify
            [1] => Disk
            [2] => VM
            [3] => Health
            [4] => iExecute
            [5] => Uptime 
            [6] => jobs
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Create
            [1] => center
            [2] => DNS
            [3] => VM 
            [4] => Storage
            [5] => Server 
            [6] => mon
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Addition
            [1] => Service 
            [2] => Upgrade
            [3] => Clear
            [4] => CMDB
            [5] => Report
            [6] => SLA
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => repository
        )

)
```

I hope you find this useful.